# How to replace string occurrences in python file?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a CSV file which contains lines of sql entries. Each sql entry, contains message which are SOH (`"\x01"`) delimited and are tag=value pairs.

```
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=70<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=237
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=71<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=238
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=72<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=239
8=Fix1.1<SOH>9=73<SOH>35=AE<SOH>10=240
```

(`<SOH>` is a placeholder for the actual character because Stack Overflow wouldn't let me include the `\x01` character in the text)

**Issue:**

- The below code snippet removes SOH to "," as expected, however, having trouble removing the tag part from the lines.

```
# Read in the file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('x01', ',') 
filedata2 = filedata.replace("=", ",") 
# Write the file out again
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata2)
```

**Output:**

```
8,Fix1.1,9,70,35,AE,10,237
8,Fix1.1,9,71,35,AE,10,238
8,Fix1.1,9,72,35,AE,10,239
8,Fix1.1,9,73,35,AE,10,240
```

I've also tried regex = re.compile ("[=]") and then loop into line reader and modify, but just returns all [=] in the print.

**Desired output:**

```
Fix1.1,70,AE,237

Fix1.1,71,AE,238

Fix1.1,72,AE,239

Fix1.1,73,AE,240
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv.reader` with `delimiter="\x01"` to split by the `SOH` character.
Then, as you read each line, split each element by `"="` and keep only the values.

```
import csv

filedata = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\x01")
    for row in reader:
        # Split each item in row
        # Keep only second element of each split
        values = [item.split("=", 1)[1] for item in row]
        filedata.append(values)

print(filedata)
```

which gives

```
[['Fix1.1', '70', 'AE', '237'], 
 ['Fix1.1', '71', 'AE', '238'], 
 ['Fix1.1', '72', 'AE', '239'], 
 ['Fix1.1', '73', 'AE', '240']]
```

You can write this list of lists to a file using `csv.writer.writerows()`.

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(filedata)
```

and your output file has:

```
Fix1.1,70,AE,237
Fix1.1,71,AE,238
Fix1.1,72,AE,239
Fix1.1,73,AE,240
```

If all you care about is to read the original file and write the new file, you can combine these two operations in one loop:

```
import csv

filedata = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file_in, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter="\x01")
    writer = csv.writer(file_out)
    for row in reader:
        # Split each item in row
        # Keep only second element of each split
        values = [item.split("=", 1)[1] for item in row]
        # filedata.append(values)
        # Instead of appending to a container list,
        # Write to the output file
        writer.writerow(values)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Pranav Hosangadi, can confirm this works. One question please, how can I keep the data in csv file as opposed to list? Used the below code, but got ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.``` So this CSV was generated by query to DB - output in tuple/list - which is converted to csv. So trying to keep in csv format as I can use for line by line comparison with another csv as opposed to list - csv module easier to control.

Comment: @test11 I'm not sure what you mean by that. When you use `writerows()` it's written to an output file. How did you manage to get that error?

Comment: ```with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(filedata)
    write.writerows(row)```

Comment: `writerows()` (notice the S at the end of the function) takes _multiple_ rows, like `filedata`. `writerow()` takes a single row, so you have to iterate over each `row in filedata` before using `writerow()` (Or just use `writerows(filedata)`). Which line throws the error? @test11

Comment: @test11 the error is because you opened your file in `wb` mode, which is write-binary. Open it in `w` like I showed in my answer.

Comment: apologies, yes I did indeed open in wb mode, which caused the issue. ```filedata = []
with open('sqlresults.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\x01")
    for row in reader:
        # Split each item in row
        # Keep only second element of each split
        values = [item.split("=", 1)[1] for item in row]
        filedata.append(values)
print(filedata)
 
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
   for row in filedata:
        write.writerows(row)``` hopefully this is an efficient way of doing so.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @PranavHosangadi - much appreciated!

Comment: @test11 _No!_ Use `writerows()` (_plural row**s**_) when you have a list of rows to write. Use `writerow()` (_singular row_) when you are iterating over `filedata` and writing one row at a time. Don't mix the two.